# issue serializing series of checkboxes for use in JQuery $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

basically I have 4 checkboxes their values are a number.

so lets say my HTML source is like this:

```
<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks[1]" value="1"/>
<input class="extra" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checks[2]" value="2"/>
<input class="extra" type="checkbox" name="checks[3]" value="3"/>
<input class="extra" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checks[4]" value="4"/>
```

I want to post checks[] with jquery post, so that the checks stay in the **specific** locations. i.e server side the array looks like this:

checks[1] is empty
check[2]  = 2
checks[4] = 4

this is what I am trying:

```
var post_data = $('input[name="checks[]"]:checked').serialize();

        $.post('search_item.php', { 'checks[]':post_data, . . .
```

Currently if I try lets say `alert(post_data)` there is nothing. So I am assuming I am doing the serializing wrong?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var post_data = $('input[name*="checks"]:checked').serialize();
alert(post_data);
```

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YAh3e/

Comment: im so confused, i was under the impression by serializing it It would just be posted like php does. How do I access the values after its been posted?

Comment: You would usually assign it to a variable or post it to your file rather than alert it.

Comment: i am posting it to my php source, but how do I access the data, essentially get the values of the array?

Comment: do you want them on the php side or the JS side?

Answer (score 0):

Try using selector `$('input[name^=checks]:chcked')`